# How does one build natively integrated SalesForce application

Tags: c#, salesforce, integration, native

Natively integrating SalesForce application using C#.
what I am looking for is the way to build and integrate a native application.

Answer (score 0):

The question is rather open-ended, but architectually, you should consider SF as a database with a web API.  From SF, you get the WSDL file for your SF instance, then your app authenticates to SF and works with the data via the API.

Of course you will need to create a web services reference, and you will need to use SF's data manipulation language - [SOQL](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm) .

You should probably reformulate your question to the task that you want to achieve (ie, authenticate to SF in a C# application, show a table with SF data OnLoad, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Basically I need my app to sit inside the Salesforce datacenter and use the Salesforce database itself.
Also, I wanted to know if its possible to use an Asp.net MVC for this?

I've heard this is possible using Native Integration in Salesforce, but am not able to find any clear information on how this is done.

So, I'm not looking to make a Connected app, i.e. one that sits outside Salesforce and makes API calls to integrate with Salesforce.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I think this is possible but I don't think you will be able to use C#.  You might want to check out the Salesforce Console Integration Toolkit.  There is also Google Apps integration in SF.  Just a thought.